# Am I broadcasting or what?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, internet-security, interference

My internet speed is bad. When I connect with a cable bypassing the router, it is good. Router seems to be fine however, and configuration is seemingly OK too. Thinking about interference, I looked into [wifi analyzer](https://matthafner.com/wifianalyzer) and saw this:

[image]

`TP-LINK_83FA` is my router, while the name of my notebook is `DESKTOP-M4AP3T8`. Wifi analyzer is on another device (android tablet).

What is going on here? Why is my notebook seen as broadcasting? Can this cause interference? Can somebody else be using my network?

As suggested in the comment, I also checked - MAC address does match too. It is listed in the analyzer under the name `DIRECT-FIDESKTOP-M4AP3T8msCU`. Description says `<Local Admin>` (description of the router says `TP-LINK technologies co., ltd`).

Comment: Can you show the full name, if the analyzer app shows it? And does the network's MAC address (BSSID) match your laptop's?

Comment: @user1686 Good point, thanks, I'll add this information: MAC address is the same. Unfortunately the analyzer does not show anything else.

Comment: Yes, someone has opened something on the same frequency as your router's AP, and this can interfere, and from the name, it looks like your Notebook. Check if you've enabled "share internet through WLAN with other devices" or something similar on your Notebook. "DIRECT-FI" may also mean it's Direct WIFI, and not an access point (AP).

Comment: @dirkt Well, occasionally I am projecting to tv screen from my notebook, and projecting to the notebook from a tablet; for that in the Windows 10 advanced sharing settings I had to turn on  public folder sharing, media streaming and file sharing connections, does it count? I don't think I would occasionally turn on my internet connection sharing.

Comment: It's easy to test: turn it off, see if it disappears in the analyzer app. And then test if the connection is better. I am not sufficiently familiar with Direct WIFI to say how much interference there is, but it will send out at least the beacons you can see in the analyzer app.

Comment: @dirkt it was the virtual adapter, see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more "settle" solution (if the "problem" is being caused by Windows's "mobil Hotspot"):

Check if the "mobil Hotspot" is turned on (Settings -> Network -> Mobil Hotspot). If the power saving is turned off it will stay on even without devices connected.

If it is turned on, turning it off will remove the "Direct Virtual Adapter" from the device manager (deactivating it is not necessary).

Comment: You were right! Now when I activate mobile hotspot, the direct virtual adapter reappears, and when I deactivate the hotspot, it disappears. So your solution is easier and more to the point.

Comment: Thanks...  although still +1 for your "final" solution

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled almost accidentally on "[How to Permanently Remove Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter](http://woshub.com/removing-microsoft-wi-fi-direct-virtual-adapter/)" at woshub.com

It turns out that I had hosted network running by default. Following instructions at the above link I was able to disallow it.

Speed is definitely better now!

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you check first if "Mobil Hotspot" was turned off (Settings -> Network -> Mobil Hotspot)??

Comment: @Albin Very interesting suggestion! Right now it is off, and unfortunately I cannot say whether it was on before - maybe it was and what I did turned it off. However, I discovered that it was possible for another device to turn it on remotely! I now blocked this too.

Comment: Deactivating the "Direct Virtual Adapter" will deactivate the mobil hotspot as well. What happens if you temporarily activate the adapter, is the access point created again right away or only if you activate the hot spot?

Comment: @Albin It is very strange, but when I reactivated it, it disappeared from the network adapter list in the device manager, and also does not reappear in the network connections list. Mobile hotspot also remains off.

Comment: Note: not sure why, but my "mobil Hotspot" created two "Direct Virtual Adapter" (both have to be disabled for this solution to work)

Comment: @Albin In my case it was similar in that when I realized "my" solution, this happened, in detail: first, by some reason my Direct Virtual Adapter was #4. When I deactivated it, a new one, Direct Virtual Adapter #5 appeared by itself. When I deactivated this one too, no other new ones appeared anymore, but they both stayed in the device manager list of network adapters. And then later, when I temporarily reactivated #4, the other one, #5, disappeared. Finally, when I switched mobile hotspot on and off, the #4 disappeared too.